# Getting British citizenship or passport?

Tags: united-kingdom, passport, uk-citizenship

I'm a Libyan citizen born in 1991 Edinburgh United Kingdom. Both of my parents are Libyan. During that time my father was living there on a student visa and I've spent a little over a year there.

I'm aware of [British Nationality Act 1981](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Nationality_Act_1981) and wondering if there's an indirect method to obtain British citizenship and/or passport?

Comment: Do you have other ties to Britain, such as a British ancestor?

Comment: @DJClayworth if you're thinking about the ancestry visa, that is only available to nationals of commonwealth countries, which Libya is not.

Comment: I believe for you to be automatically British at birth one of your parents would needed to have no immigration restrictions at the time (i.e. indefinite leave to remain/permanent residence), so a student visa unfortunately wouldn't be enough.

Comment: @DJClayworth I have none.

Comment: @kiradotee Actually I'm not sure of the Visa exactly. I just took a look on my father's old passport and I noticed there are many stamps with **F2** code. I'm not sure what does that mean!

Answer (score 1):

The government website has a checklist you can use. For people born between 1983 and 2000 [this is the relevant page](https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizenship/born-in-the-uk-between-1-january-1983-and-1-october-2000).

Based on it you’ll be a British citizen if when you were born at least one of your parents was either:

- a British citizen
- an Irish citizen living in the UK
- a citizen of a country that was in the EU or the EEA at the time AND living in the UK, and working or studying here
- a citizen of another country with one of the following immigration status:

  - indefinite leave to remain (ILR)
  - right of abode
  - right of re-admission

As you mentioned your father had only a student visa when you were born, which is unfortunately not one of the categories mentioned above. You can [check here](https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizenship/your-parents-immigration-status-when-you-were-born) on more details about these three categories.

Also he wasn't a citizen of an EU/EEA country at the time you were born as well.

Based on these details you are most likely **not** a British citizen.